# JQuery audio source undefined

Tags: jquery, pug

I'm trying to play an mp3 when a button is clicked.

The following error occurs: TypeError: dontlose is undefined

Jade:

```
audio#actrl(preload="auto")
      source(src="sound/quickscope.mp3",type="audio/mpeg")
      source(src="sound/dontloseyourway.mp3",type="audio/mpeg")
      source(src="sound/blumenkranz.mp3",type="audio/mpeg")
      No audio for you!
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var dontlose= $("#actrl")[1];
  $("#1").click(function(){
    dontlose.play();
  });
});
```

Comment: Why the `[1];`? If you are trying to address the DOM element, try [0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously have multiple ID's or are forgetting that indexes start at 0, which is causing an issue. This line:

```
var dontlose= $("#actrl")[1];
```

makes no sense. The ID selector expects 1 result, therefore the `[1]` will return undefined. You should use `[0]` to get the actual element, or use `getElementById`